# React Native script brings and renders the contents of sample file movies.json successfully from their server but not from my server

Tags: json, react-native

I have copied and tested a script which works perfectly when the URL is the .json file on reactnative.dev's site. I have copied the same JSON array and placed the contents in a file with the same name, but changing movieURL to the address on my own server's address invokes a "TypeError: Failed to fetch" error! Any ideas?

```
// get data from this URL!
//const movieURL = "https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/api/api/movies.json";
const movieURL = "https://reactnative.dev/movies.json";
```

I started using React Native just the other day, so I don't have too much experience. Explanations on the internet are really limited. I tried a couple of solutions such as experimenting with .htaccess etc to no avail. I also tried putting headers, but that was like a shot in the dark.

The contents of movies.json on their and my server:

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
    { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
    { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
    { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial with my localhost, I came to realize that I need some sort of tool in order to make the .json file "reachable" in the first place. After installing json-server

```
$ npm install -g json-server
```

I had to invoke

```
json-server --watch movies.json
```

which produced the following output:

```
Loading movies.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/data

  Home
  http://localhost:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...
```

with entering the proper parameters in the url:

```
const movieURL = "http://localhost:3000/data";
```

I could now load the data into my app. I'm still awaiting answer from the web hotel, as to whether I need to do something similar on their server using SSH or whether they have a ready solution for it. Also, I needed to modify the data itself to:

```
{
  "data":
  {
    "title": "The Basics - Networking",
    "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
    "movies": [
      { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
      { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
      { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
      { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
      { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Compare it to the original data structure listed below!

```
  {
    "title": "The Basics - Networking",
    "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
    "movies": [
      { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
      { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
      { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
      { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
      { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
    ]
  }
```